# Concatenation of Markov processes and independence

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In chapter 14 of [Sharpe's General Theory of Markov Processes](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/general-theory-of-markov-processes/sharpe/978-0-12-639060-5) the concatenation of Markov processes $X^1$ and $X^2$ is described. I've posed the relevant part at the bottom of this post.

It is rather simple to show that when the transfer kernel $K$ does not depend on the first argument (i.e. is simply a measure) then $\tilde X^1(\omega_1,\omega_2):=X^1(\omega_1)$ and $\tilde X^2(\omega_1,\omega_2):=X^2(\omega_2)$ are $\operatorname P^{x_1}$-independent for all $x_1\in E_1$.

However, I wonder how that result can be generalized when $K$ is general. What I really would like to obtain is that, for any $x_1\in E_1$ and any bounded measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$, $$A:=\int_0^Rf\left(\tilde X^1_t\right)\:{\rm d}t$$ and $$B:=\int_0^\infty f\left(\tilde X^2_t\right)\:{\rm d}t$$ are $\operatorname P^{x_1}$-independent. Is that (maybe in a slightly corrected way) possible?

From Theorem 14.18, I would expect something like "$\tilde X^1$ and $\tilde X^2$ are conditionally $\operatorname P^{x_1}$-independent given $\tilde X^1_{R-}$" (in case that $X^1$ is sufficiently regular and $T$ is of the special form in the example below its definition). Maybe the desired claim should be restated with some conditionally probability instead, but I'm not sure.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]